Is there a way to connect the lines of a scatter+line plot with the ends of the markers, instead of the centers in Python?
I use this code to make a scatter+line plot with Matplotlib:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
zero = [1,2,3,4,5]
eq = [1.2,3,5,7,11]     
plt.plot(zero,'r_--', eq,'k_--',ms = 30, markeredgewidth=5)
plt.xlabel('Steps',fontsize=20, fontname='Helvetica', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Steps',fontweight='bold',fontsize=20, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4], fontsize=20, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.yticks(fontsize =18, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.show()     
plt.close()

However, the lines in the resulting graph connect to the centers of the markers, as in the red example in the image. How can I get a result like the black example instead, where the lines connect to the endpoints of the markers?


As per @J_H suggestion, you have to cheat a bit and -for each datapoint- introduce two datapoints corresponding to the ends of the markers.
You can use the following list comprehensions to define the new datapoints
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
zero = [1,2,3,4,5]
eq = [1.2,3,5,7,11]

# For each datapoint in your initial dataset, define two points, with same Y of the original point, and X values one slightly smaller and one slightly larger than the actual datapoint (i.e. x - offset and x + offset).
offset = 0.175 # adjust the offset value manually or -better- based on marker size

zeroX = [i
         for x in range(len(zero)) 
         for i in (x-offset, x+offset)]
zeroY = [i
         for y in zero
         for i in (y, y)]
eqX =   [i
         for x in range(len(eq)) 
         for i in (x-offset, x+offset)]
eqY =   [i
         for y in eq 
         for i in (y, y)]

plt.plot(zeroX, zeroY, eqX, eqY) # plot the lines without markers
plt.plot(zero,'r_', eq,'k_',ms = 30, markeredgewidth=5) # plot the markers only 
plt.xlabel('Steps',fontsize=20, fontname='Helvetica', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Steps',fontweight='bold',fontsize=20, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4], fontsize=20, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.yticks(fontsize =18, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.show()     
plt.close()

and get the plot below as a result

As commented in the code, it would be better to have the offset automatically adjusted based on the marker size rather than manually.
Hope this helps!


How can I get a result ... where the lines connect to the endpoints of the markers?

Introduce new datapoints, corresponding to the endpoints of markers.
Ask matplotlib to alternately plot dotted lines,
then solid lines for markers, then dotted lines....
